# v-usb button press and release

Tags: c++, usb, arduino, avr

I'm trying to use [V-USB](http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html) on an [AVR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR) [microcontroller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) to mimic a [HID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device) keyboard, and I found how to send keys and how to release ALL of them, by calling usbSetInterrupt() with 0 for the key value, but is there a way to release one key and not another?

I'm using this for a game controller so, for example, I'm holding down the button that corresponds to Left-Arrow and press and release the A button. I want it to register as:

- Left Arrow Press
- A Press
- A Release
- Left Arrow Release

But all I can do now is basically momentary press on each. Each time I press a button down it registers as press AND release on the computer. Is there a way to call usbSetInterrupt() or something else telling it that only one of the previously pressed keys has now been released?

Comment: Can you post come code, that would make things a bit easier.